# How to create OSMdroid tiles from my own image

Tags: android, osmdroid

Is there an easy way to created OSMtiles from my own 1 layered image file.

Ex.  Say i have a hiking map, and i wish to import this into my Osmdroid app. Then i need to create tiles similar to how MOBAC does it, but i just want them created from my 1 map/image file, and to work on all/several zoom levels.
Is there any programs or java/android code to create this?

Comment: Noone knows a way?  Guess i will have to work on some code myself and hope i can get it working

Comment: did you find some solution?